# Sampling uniformly from the vertices of a polytope

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, convex-polytopes, linear-programming

I'm looking for a reference on how to sample uniformly (and preferably efficiently, elegantly, etc.) from the vertices of a polytope. I gather that [enumerating vertices is hard](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-87363-3_17). I also note the MO questions [Uniformly Sampling from Convex Polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9854/) and [Is it possible to sample uniformly on the surface of a high-dimensional polytope?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98027/). A bit of poking around Google Scholar hasn't turned anything up.

Comment: I recently asked a question that turned out to be equivalent: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42705/can-one-efficiently-uniformly-sample-a-neighbor-of-a-vertex-in-the-graph-of-a-po I found some interesting references, but nothing definitive yet.

Comment: I think I was able to show it is NP-hard. Take a look and see if you believe my argument. :-)

Comment: It is $NP$-hard. See updated answer.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt- Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one efficient approach, performing a random walk with a rapid mixing time, that has been implemented for a particular class of polytopes, but which might well be adaptable to a more general setting: [Random Walks on the Vertices of Transportation Polytopes](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/mcryan/cdms-jour.pdf) (2008).

Comment: Interesting bit from the first page: "Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) has not been well explored as a means of sampling, or approximately counting, vertices of general polytopes."

Comment: ...and from the conclusions: "The question of whether we can sample vertices of a general [transportation polytope], when the number of sources is not constant, is still open."