# Sampling uniformly in a ball of radius $\epsilon$ in the space of dicrete r.v. of m modalities for the total variation metric

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, algorithms, simulation

I am looking for some reference or an algorithm that allows to sample uniformly in the ball centered at a discrete random variable of n modalities in the TV distance.

For the record for 2 discrete random variables the total variation distance between them is defined by :
$$d_{TV}(X,Y)= \sum _{i=1}^{n} |p_i-q_i|$$
where the laws of X and Y are defined by the vectors $(p_1,...,p_n)$ and $(q_1,...,q_n)$ with $ \sum _{i=1}^{n} p_i=1$ and $ \sum _{i=1}^{n} q_i=1$

This is not as simple as it may look but quite natural problem though but I couldn't find any reference for this problem.

Edit : I will try to clarify the problem, the objective is to sample in the space of discrete random variables with $n$ modalities not sampling from those random variables. Any point in this space is thus characterized by the n dimensional vector of their law i.e. $p=(p_1,...,p_n)$ such that $ \sum _{i=1}^{n} p_i=1$. This space is endowed with the total variation distance defined above. For a fixed point $X$ or alternatively $p$ in this space I can define a ball with respect to this metric for some $0\leq\epsilon\leq 1$ (even though the case $\epsilon= 1$ is the whole space unless mistaken).

So once I have fixed $p$ and $\epsilon$ I am looking to sample uniformly in this ball, to get $\tilde{q}$.
For the $\epsilon= 1$ case I think that a Dirichlet law with parameters $(1,...,1)$ might do the trick because unless mistaken it allows to sample uniformly over the $n-simplex$ but for the restricted case of a non trivial ball I am a bit confused and do not have a clue how to make a sampling algorithm that might just do the trick.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to sample: random variables (r.v.'s) with values in the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$? Do you want to specify the probability space(s) on which such r.v's are defined? How do you define the uniform distribution on the set of such r.v.'s?

Comment: Hi I have edited my post I hope it makes more sense

Comment: This is still unclear: "the objective is to sample in the space of discrete random variables".  Why random variables (which are real-valued functions)? It seems you rather want to sample just from a neighborhood of a point of the simplex, right?

Comment: Right, I identify those points to the laws of discrete r.v. with n modalities, this why I interpret this as sampling in the space of those r.v. endowed with the TV metric.

Comment: Is your $n$ large?

Comment: Well typically n would be something like 4 or 5, some outlier cases might reach 30 at most though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the uniform sampling from general convex polytopes, see e.g. [Answer 1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/162327/36721), [Answer 2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9858/36721), other answers to this [Question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9854/36721), and further references given there. Also, for instance, [Fast MCMC Sampling Algorithms on Polytopes](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume19/18-158/18-158.pdf).

---

Here is an example with $1000$ sample points for $n=3$, $q=(.2, .3, .5)$, and $\epsilon=.4$, generated by a Markov Chain Monte Carlo method (with $5$ steps for each of the $1000$ sample points:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great answer which is very well illustrated.