# Measure of intersection of polyhedral cone with unit sphere

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, convex-polytopes

Let $C$ be a pointed polyhedral cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $S^{n-1}$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Given a description of the supporting hyperplanes of $C$ is there an algorithm for computing the spherical measure of $C \cap S^{n-1}$?  I suppose you could randomly generate points uniformly distributed on the unit sphere, and test each point to see if it is in $C$.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Is the base of the cone at the origin?

Comment: @Igor: I call that bit of a cone the vertex, and I call the other end (when there is one) the base.

Comment: @Andreas: yes, of course, base was a poorly chosen term...

Comment: Yes, the vertex is the origin

Comment: Things may depend on how the set of supporting planes is described.
Is it given as normal plane to a convex hull of some finite set in $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: The methods to attack your problem may not differ much from those used to find the volume of a convex polytope.  See the MO question, "Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/

Answer (score 3):

This is in general as hard as computing the volume of an Euclidean polytope, but there are reductions for even dimensional polytopes to volumes of lower-dimensional things (of which there may, of course, be an exponential number). See
http://www.math.ru.nl/~heckman/Heck_7.pdf
(he mostly talks about the hyperbolic case, but the spherical case is identical).

Answer (score 1):

For very special classes of cones, there are combinatorial formulas related to these questions, e.g.

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~klivans/reflection.pdf

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~klivans/volumes.pdf