# Number of neigbour Voronoi cells for a random set of points on S^k or cube [-1, 1]^k? 

Tags: it.information-theory, geometry, pr.probability

Consider $S^k \subset  R^{k+1} $.  Sample $N$ points by say uniform distribution. (Example k=120, N=2^24, i.e. N>>k ).

Consider [Voronoi cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) around each point.

How many neighbours would a cell have ? I mean neigbours are the cells which have non empty intersection. "How many" means average over distribution. (Clearly it is less than N,
but what is it behaviour ? N/C, sqrt(N) or what ?)

Actually I more interested not about the sphere but about the cube: take unit cube $[-1, 1]^k$.
And take randomly some number $N$ of its vertexes.
The same questions.

---

Motivatation:

As I tried to explain in this [MO quest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101240/complexity-of-convex-polytope-volume-calculation-volume-of-voronoi-cell-err/101245#101245) these problems are related to decoding noise signal. This question can be translated in this language as follows - if there chance to do some "preprocessing" such that it would significantly reduce decoding complexity.
I mean in the answer is much smaller than N, then yes, otherwise, not.

Comment: In closely related Poisson-Voronoi tessellation, the degree grows exponentially with the dimension (I believe it is roughly $2^k$ up to lower order multiplicative terms, but I can't find a reference now). So the relevant condition seems to be whether $N$ is bigger then this. For your example parameters, I would expect most pairs of points to be adjacent.

Answer (score 4):

When $k=2$, you can use combinatorics to avoid any relation with probability. From Euler formula, one gets that the mean degree of a graph with $N$ vertices on $S^2$ is $6-\frac{12}N$ (see e.g. *Proofs from the book*, section on Euler formula).

Applying this to the neighbors graph of your tesselation, you get that the average number of neighbors of a cell is bounded by $6$ independently of $N$.

For this you have to rule out cells that touch by a corner only (otherwise the graph need not be planar), but I guess this only happen with null probability.

Comment: @Benoît Kloeckner thank you very much ! so  probably this number mainly depends on $k$. Is the dependence known ?

Comment: I don't know more than I wrote. The argument above does not extend to higher dimensions as they are, I do not know if there are any restriction on the neighbors graph of a Voronoi diagram in higher dimension.

Answer (score 4):

This was studied by Miles in the seventies. A good reference is Schneider and Weil's book. The relevant results are in [section 10.2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/schneiderweilextract.pdf)