# Estimating the volume of a union of balls

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, convex-polytopes

Let $\{ B_i \}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of $n$ ball in the unit cube $C$ of dimension $d$.

If I want to estimate
$$
\frac{ \lambda \left( \cup B_i \right) }{\lambda\left( C \right) }, \tag{1}
$$
where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue Measure, is it ok to sample uniformly in the cube then count the number of point which fall in any ball?

I ask, because I saw a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/979/24451) saying that estimating the volume of a convex body is hard, and one needs special algorithm.

Is the estimation of (1) similar to the Dyer, Frieze, Kannan context, and a naive Monte Carlo is doomed to failed?  If so why?

From some numerical tests, it seems to work.
Especially that I know in advance the volume of $\cup B_i$ is at least half the volume of the cube.

Comment: Adding to the question, is random sampling considered better or worse than counting points on a discrete grid?

Comment: What dimension are we talking about?  How many balls?  Naive Monte Carlo will converge, but it won't converge very fast; you get an error of about $1/\sqrt{n}$ in your ratio after $n$ samples.

Comment: @tmyklebu It's a 500 dimensional space, with 2,000 balls. ($d=500$, $n=2000$)

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: OK, that's really easy.  The volume is, to a few hundred decimal places, zero.  The biggest ball that fits inside the unit cube in 500 dimensions has volume $(\pi/4)^{250} / 250! \approxeq 2 \cdot 10^{-519}$, and you don't have many of them.  Are you working with the intersection of a bunch of balls with the cube instead?

Comment: @tmyklebu You raised a good point. I will check again my numerics, because it gives me a non-zero volume. But, you are right that I'm working with the intersection of a bunch of balls with the cube. So the balls are not constrained to fit inside the cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive Monte Carlo will always work, probabilistically, by the Law of Large Numbers. The problem only arises if you want guaranteed correctness, 100% chance as opposed to say 99.999%.

Comment: The other problem is that convergence is very slow -- if you want more than a couple of correct digits, it might take quite long even on a modern computer.