# Formula for volume of a convex polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, simplicial-volume

So I've been searching around the internet for some answers to this, but I currently have a set of linear constraints: $Ax = b, Cx \le d$ for matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}$, and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$. I would like to deduce a formula for the volume of the set of feasible $x$:s that satisfy these constraints. It would be great if anyone could point me in a good direction, maybe this can't be solved analytically, in this case, maybe there is an approximation?

Answer (score 11):

Here is one paper, whose introduction will lead you to others:

> Lasserre, Jean B., and Eduardo S. Zeron. "A new algorithm for the volume of a convex polytope." [arXiv math/0106168](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106168) (2001).

If you want a faster but approximate algorithm:

> Emiris, Ioannis Z., and Vissarion Fisikopoulos. "Efficient random-walk methods for approximating polytope volume." In *Proceedings 13th Symposium on Computational Geometry*, p. 318. ACM, 2014. [ACM link](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3194656).

Also addressed in a 2009 MO question:
"[Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope](https://mathoverflow.net/q/979/6094)."

Answer (score 5):

The volume of the resulting convex polytope is given by the leading coefficient of the [Ehrhart (quasi)polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial#Ehrhart_quasi-polynomials) if all matrices in your half-space description are rational (that is, have only rational entries) and the resulting polyhedron is compact. Ehrhart quasipolynomials can be computed using [Normaliz](https://www.normaliz.uni-osnabrueck.de) or [Latte](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software.php). These software are open source so if you're interested in how the algorithms run just have a look.